# How do I make Application.SendKeys "{TAB}" run? I am trying to use this on a form filling application

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I have tried this method before on a browser where I fill in details for a form using Excel VBA, but when I'm trying to use this for a software, it isn't working. It probably shouldn't have anything to do with what I'm using because I'm just using the `SendKeys` function when I manually click inside the first text box on the window.

```
Sub enter_details()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim des, name, addr As String
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#

    For i = 5 To 15
        des = Cells(i, 2).Value
        name = Cells(i, 3).Value
        addr = Cells(i, 4).Value
        
        Application.SendKeys (des)
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        Application.SendKeys ("{TAB}")
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        SendKeys (name)
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        Application.SendKeys ("{TAB}")
.
.
.
    Next
End Sub
```

Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SendKeys` will always run on the window that has focus (is on top). Since `Set keys = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` does not open any window it cannot be run there. You need to run something in the shell you have created, in your code there is nothing run in your shell yet. It is very unclear what you tried to do with that code. • Actually `SendKeys` is the most unreliable method to accomplish things. Try to avoid it at any cost.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have the window where I have the data to be entered on top. I know it is unreliable, but right now I don't have a lot of option with the task that I have.

Comment: Then you should show how this window got there. Your code does not open any window. You need to show the relevant code then. See [mcve]. In order to help you, we need somehow need to reproduce your issue. With the code you show we can't.

Comment: The code is not opening any window. I'm opening it manually. The window where I'm trying to get data filled is a software and it has a form. I have to enter the name, description and address fields from an excel sheet. I run the code, open the window and set it to top manually. The rest of the data is being entered, but the TAB isn't working. I've updated my original question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some notes: `Dim des, name, addr As String` only declares `addr` as `String` but all the others as `Variant` in VBA you need to declare a type for **every** variable `Dim des As String, name As String, addr As String`, also row counting variables need to be of type `Long` as Excel has more rows that fit into `Integer`.

Also the brackets you use here `Application.SendKeys ("{TAB}")` are not doing what you expect them to do. It must be either:

```
Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"  'no Call and no `=` sign no brackets
```

or

```
Call Application.SendKeys("{TAB}")
```

Finally if your application does not react to the tab but to all other `SendKeys` then this application is somehow interfering with `SendKeys` (incompatible) or it is blocking something. Actually as you wrote the code it should work. I cannot reproduce your issue and I definitely see the tab being sent.

Comment: I tried everything that you've mentioned. And yes, it does send tab, but it just isn't working out for my application. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @KeithSaldanha Well then the only thing I can imagine is either tab has no effect in this application or the application blocks it in some way. Or the window loses focus before the tab gets there.

Comment: It's neither of them. Tabs work, and it remains in focus. It probably is blocking tabs. I'm gonna try some other commands like ENTER or ALT+F4 to see if that works.